# Reductive group with simply connected derived group has all root groups $\mathrm{SL}_2$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups, geometric-representation-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\PGL{PGL}$**Motivation**: I am trying to understand why the Deligne-Langlands conjectures are only stated for $p$-adic reductive groups with connected center. I know that in such a case, the Langlands dual has simply connected derived group. I am trying to understand why this is a desirable condition.

1. Suppose $G$ is a complex reductive group (playing the role of the Langlands dual in the statement of the Deligne-Langlands conjecture) with datum $(X,Y, R, R^{\vee}, \Pi)$. Suppose that the derived group of $G$ is simply connected. Is it the case that all root groups in $G$ are in fact $\SL_2$? More precisely, is it true that all root homomorphisms $h_{\alpha}: \SL_2\to G$ has image isomorphic to $\SL_2$? What is the precise obstruction for a root homomorphism taking image $\PGL_2$?
2. Assuming that the answer to the answer to question 1 is affirmative, does this necessarily imply that for all $\alpha\in \Pi$, we have $\alpha^{\vee}\notin 2Y$? Probably this one is easy but I cannot see it.

It seems we need both of the above questions to have positive answer; otherwise, I am rather lost.

Comment: Related:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270205/centralizers-of-subtori-in-reductive-groups-derived-subgroups

Comment: Specifically, I think that [@YCor's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/270280) answers your question.

Comment: No, the fundamental group of $\operatorname{PGL}_2$ is $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, with generator the cocharacter $\varpi_\alpha = \frac1 2\alpha^\vee : t \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} t & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thanks to @spin for [pointing out](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391643/reductive-group-with-simply-connected-derived-group-has-all-root-groups-mathrm/391666#comment998972_391666) that I meant to refer to an [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/270280) by @‍nfdc23, not by @‍YCor.

Answer (score 6):

$\newcommand\Z{\mathbb Z}$Point 1 has already been answered by [@spin](https://mathoverflow.net/a/391649), and by [@nfdc23](https://mathoverflow.net/a/270280) at [Centralizers of subtori in reductive groups, derived subgroups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270205/centralizers-of-subtori-in-reductive-groups-derived-subgroups).  It is also Proposition 2.1(i) of [Kac and Weisfeiler - Coadjoint action of a semi-simple algebraic group and the center of the enveloping algebra in characteristic $p$](https://doi.org/10.1016/1385-7258(76)90059-7).

In light of point 1, point 2 is the same as asking whether there are a group $G$ with derived group $G' = \operatorname{SL}_2$, a maximal torus $T$ in $G$, and a root $\alpha$ of $T$ in $\operatorname{Lie}(G)$ such that $\lambda = \frac1 2\alpha^\vee$ lies in the cocharacter lattice of $T' = G' \cap T$.  This cannot happen.

Indeed, suppose it did.  Note that the adjoint quotient $G_\text{ad} = G/\operatorname Z(G)$ is $\operatorname{PGL}_2$.  Since the composition $\operatorname{GL}_1 \xrightarrow\lambda T' \to T_\text{ad} \mathrel{:=} T/\operatorname Z(G) \xrightarrow\alpha \operatorname{GL}_1$ is the identity, we find that $\operatorname{im} \lambda$ is a subtorus of $T'$ that projects isomorphically to $T_\text{ad}$.  Since $T'$ is $1$-dimensional, actually it equals $\operatorname{im} \lambda$; that is, the adjoint quotient restricts to an isomorphism $T' \to T_\text{ad}$.  However, the adjoint-quotient map $G' \cong \operatorname{SL}_2 \to G_\text{ad} \cong \operatorname{PGL}_2$ has a non-trivial kernel on every maximal torus.

Comment: I don't find an answer by YCor in the link, maybe you mean the one by Paul Levy.

Comment: @spin, my mistake; I meant [@‍nfdc23](https://mathoverflow.net/a/270280).  (That's the answer linked at the name.)  Thank you for [catching](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391643/reductive-group-with-simply-connected-derived-group-has-all-root-groups-mathrm/391666#comment998972_391666) my error!

Answer (score 3):

I think looking at Steinberg's lecture notes might be instructive for this question.

Following the notation $h_{\alpha}(t)$ defined in Steinberg's lecture notes (Lemma 19), the homomorphism $\operatorname{SL}_2 \rightarrow G$ corresponding to a root $\alpha$ has image $\operatorname{PGL}_2$ if and only if $h_{\alpha}(-1) = 1$.

By Lemma 28 (c) in Steinberg, you have $h_{\alpha}(-1) = 1$ if and only if $\langle \mu, \alpha \rangle \in 2 \mathbb{Z}$ for all weights $\mu$ in the weight lattice corresponding to $G$.

If $G$ is simply connected, you have the full weight lattice, so for any root $\alpha$ there exists  a weight $\mu$ such that $\langle \mu, \alpha \rangle = 1$. Therefore for all roots $\alpha$, the corresponding homomorphism $\operatorname{SL}_2 \rightarrow G$ has image $\operatorname{SL}_2$.

**EDIT:** Suppose that $G$ is simple. Using the result above and examining the root systems case-by-case, we conclude the following:

The homomorphism $\operatorname{SL}_2 \rightarrow G$ corresponding to a root $\alpha$ has image $\operatorname{PGL}_2$ if and only if $G$ is of adjoint type $B_n$ and $\alpha$ is a short root.

**proof:** In the simply connected case there always exists a weight $\mu$ such that $\langle \mu, \alpha \rangle = 1$. In the simply laced case (except adjoint $A_1 = B_1 = C_1$), for every root $\alpha$ there exists another root $\beta$ such that $\langle \beta, \alpha \rangle = 1$. This is also true for type $C_n$ if $n \geq 3$. (It suffices to check this for simple $\alpha$, and then it is clear from the Dynkin diagram.)

The remaining case is $G$ of adjoint type $B_n$. In type $B_n$ for $n \geq 2$, for each long root $\alpha$ there exists a root $\beta$ such that $\langle \beta, \alpha \rangle = 1$.

For a short root $\alpha$ in type $B_n$ ($n \geq 1$), we have $\langle \beta, \alpha \rangle \in 2 \mathbb{Z}$ for all roots $\beta$. In the adjoint case the weight lattice is spanned by the roots, so we conclude that for adjoint type $B_n$, a map $\operatorname{SL}_2 \rightarrow G$ corresponding to a short root has image $\operatorname{PGL}_2$.

(**Another edit:** Just a minor note, the simple case immediately answers the question for reductive $G$ as well.)

Comment: Here the reductive group has nothing to do with the question, because the image of the homomorphism $h_\alpha\colon {\rm SL}_2\to G$ is contained in the derived group $G^{\rm der}=[G,G]$, which by assumption is simply connected.

Comment: Let $G$ be a *semisimple* $\Bbb C$-group. I think that if the image of  the  homomorphism $h_\alpha\colon {\rm SL}_2\to G$ is isomorphic to ${\rm PGL}_2$, then this image is a *direct factor* of $G$.

Comment: The notation you used for the map $\operatorname{SL}_2 \rightarrow G$ is a bit unfortunate, since it clashes with the notation $h_{\alpha}(t)$ used in Steinberg. Lemma 19 is just where the definition of $h_{\alpha}(t)$ is. Lemma 28 (c) is what you want to use, since $\operatorname{SL}_2 \rightarrow G$ maps $\begin{pmatrix} t & 0 \\ 0 & t^{-1} \end{pmatrix}$ to $h_{\alpha}(t)$.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi: What if $G$ is of adjoint type $C_2$, and $\alpha$ is a short root? Anyway doing a case-by-case for all root systems to check which images are $\operatorname{PGL}_2$ should be routine.

Comment: @spin, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391643/reductive-group-with-simply-connected-derived-group-has-all-root-groups-mathrm#comment998830_391649), see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270205/centralizers-of-subtori-in-reductive-groups-derived-subgroups.

Comment: @spin: you are right, and my comment about a direct factor is erroneous.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, not to pile on about it, but surely you had an interesting motivation to make [that claim](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391643/reductive-group-with-simply-connected-derived-group-has-all-root-groups-mathrm#comment998819_391649).  What intuition suggested it?

Comment: @LSpice: I mistakenly remembered my old work where I considered *simply connected* groups.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, since we can't have $\operatorname{PGL}_2$ as a direct factor of a simply connected group, what is the relevant result in the simply connected setting?

Comment: @spin, this case-by-case analysis is the same as in [@PaulLevy](https://mathoverflow.net/a/270272)'s and [@nfdc23](https://mathoverflow.net/a/270280)'s answers to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270205/centralizers-of-subtori-in-reductive-groups-derived-subgroups, right?

Comment: @LSpice: Yes, it is the same result, but mine is more elementary in the sense that it just uses the basic definitions of Chevalley groups from Steinberg's notes. Paul Levy gives a more general approach that works for all SL2's (labeled Dynkin diagrams, Jacobson-Morozov theorem etc).

Answer (score 0):

This restriction that the dual group have simply-connected derived subgroup is not actually needed for the Kazhdan-Lusztig parametrization to hold. This is worked out in Reeder's paper *Isogenies of Hecke algebras and a Langlands correspondence for ramified principal series representations*, available [here](https://www.ams.org/ert/2002-006-04/S1088-4165-02-00167-X/S1088-4165-02-00167-X.pdf).

In general this condition is convenient in this setting because some very useful things are nicer in $G^\vee$-equivariant $K$-theory when $G^\vee$ is simply connected.